# Best algorithm for series expansion of Rational function

Tags: c++, algorithm, taylor-series

I need to code function in C++ which efficiently finds coefficients of Taylor Series of given rational function (P(x) / Q(x)).

Function parameters will be power of polynomials (equal in nominator and denominator), two arrays with coefficients of polynomials and number of terms in expansion.

My idea was following.
Consider identity

```
P(x) / Q(x) = R(x) + ...
```

Where `R(x)` is a polynomial with number of terms equal to number of coefficients I need to find. Then I can multiply both sides with `Q(x)` and get

```
P(x) = R(x) * Q(x)

R(x) * Q(x) - P(x) = 0
```

Therefore, all coefficients should be zero. This is system of equations which have *O(n^3)* algorithm to solve. *O(n^3)* is not that fast as I wanted.

Is there any faster algorithm?

I know that coefficients of series are satisfying linear recurrence relation.
This makes me think that *O(n)* algorithm is possible.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Thanks, that simplifies task. But how I can find `1 / Q(x)` with long division? I thought with division I only find quotient and remainder.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Thanks! Avoiding separation also will speed up things, because multiplication will be *O(n*m)*, where n - number of terms, m - degree. By the way, I don't understang why my answer is marked as too broad, it requests one specific algorithm.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat There you go :) Maybe we should start a topic about the state of [algorithm] on meta. There's definitely some general decision making to be done about whether to move these questions to CS

Comment: @NiklasB. Feel free. I might participate, but (i) I think MSO is seriously broken and (ii) I don't appreciate answers from people whose SO rep/MSO rep ratio is in the single digits (or worse, less than 1).

Comment: @DavidEisenstat And there you have it, your second argument is no longer valid :)

Comment: @NiklasB. Feel free to link the question when it happens =P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The algorithm that I'm about to describe is justified mathematically by [formal power series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series). Every function with a Taylor series has a formal power series. The converse is not true, but if we do arithmetic on functions with Taylor series and get a function with a Taylor series, then we can do the same arithmetic with formal power series and get the same answer.

The long division algorithm for formal power series is like the [long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division) algorithm that you may have learned in school. I'll demonstrate it on the example `(1 + 2 x)/(1 - x - x^2)`, which has coefficients equal to the [Lucas numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number).

The denominator must have a nonzero constant term. We start by writing the numerator, which is the first residual.

```
             --------
1 - x - x^2 ) 1 + 2 x
```

[
We divide the residual's lowest-order term (`1`) by the denominator's constant term (`1`) and put the quotient up top.

```
              1
             --------
1 - x - x^2 ) 1 + 2 x
```

Now we multiply `1 - x - x^2` by `1` and subtract it from the current residual.

```
              1
             --------
1 - x - x^2 ) 1 + 2 x
              1 -   x - x^2
              -------------
                  3 x + x^2
```

Do it again.

```
              1 + 3 x
             --------
1 - x - x^2 ) 1 + 2 x
              1 -   x -   x^2
              ---------------
                  3 x +   x^2
                  3 x - 3 x^2 - 3 x^3
                  -------------------
                        4 x^2 + 3 x^3
```

And again.

```
              1 + 3 x + 4 x^2
             ----------------
1 - x - x^2 ) 1 + 2 x
              1 -   x -   x^2
              ---------------
                  3 x +   x^2
                  3 x - 3 x^2 - 3 x^3
                  -------------------
                        4 x^2 + 3 x^3
                        4 x^2 - 4 x^3 - 4 x^4
                        ---------------------
                                7 x^3 + 4 x^4
```

And again.

```
              1 + 3 x + 4 x^2 + 7 x^3
             ------------------------
1 - x - x^2 ) 1 + 2 x
              1 -   x -   x^2
              ---------------
                  3 x +   x^2
                  3 x - 3 x^2 - 3 x^3
                  -------------------
                        4 x^2 + 3 x^3
                        4 x^2 - 4 x^3 - 4 x^4
                        ---------------------
                                7 x^3 + 4 x^4
                                7 x^3 - 7 x^4 - 7 x^4
                                ---------------------
                                       11 x^4 + 7 x^5
```

The individual divisions were kind of boring because I used a divisor with a leading `1`, but if I had used, say, `2 - 2 x - 2 x^2`, then all of the coefficients in the quotient would be divided by `2`.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot! All expansions I wanted to find are with integer coefficients, this likely guarantees that leading coefficient will be 1.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in `O(n log n)` time for arbitrary `P` and `Q` of degree `n`. More precisely this can be done in `M(n)`, where `M(n)` is the complexity of polynomial multiplication which itself can be done in `O(n log n)`.

First of, the first `n` terms of a series expansion can be viewed simply as a polynomial of degree `n-1`.

Assume you are interested in the first `n` terms of the series expansion of `P(x)/Q(x)`. There exists an algorithm that will compute the inverse of `Q` in `M(n)` time as defined above.

Inverse `T(x)` of `Q(x)` satisfies `T(x) * Q(x) = 1 + O(x^N)`. I.e. `T(x) * Q(x)` is precisely `1` plus some error term whose coeficients all come after the first `n` terms we are interested in, so we can just drop them.

Now `P(x) / Q(x)` is simply `P(x) * T(x)` which is just another polynomial multiplication.

You can find an implementation that computes the aforementioned inverse in my open source library [Altruct](https://github.com/plamenko/altruct). See the [series.h](https://github.com/plamenko/altruct/blob/master/include/structure/math/series.h) file. Assuming you already have a method that computes the product of two polyinomials, the code that calculates the inverse is about 10 lines long (a variant of divide-and-conquer).

The actual algorithm is as follows:
Assume `Q(x) = 1 + a1*x + a2*x^2 + ...`. If `a0` is not `1`, you can simply divide `Q(x)` and later its inverse `T(x)` with `a0`.
Asume that at each step you have `L` terms of the inverse so that `Q(x) * T_L(x) = 1 + x^L * E_L(x)` for some error `E_L(x)`. Initially `T_1(X) = 1`. If you plug this in in the above you'll get `Q(x) * T_1(x) = Q(x) = 1 + x^1 * E_1(x)` for some `E_1(x)` which means this holds for `L=1`. Let's now double `L` at each step. You can get `E_L(x)` from the previous step as `E_L(x) = (Q(x) * T_L(x) - 1) / x^L`, or implementation-wise, just drop the first `L` coefficients of the product. You can then compute `T_2L(x)` from the previous step as `T_2L(x) = T_L(x) - x^L * E_L(x) * T_L(x)`. The error will be `E_2L(x) = - E_L(x)^2`. Let's now check that the induction step holds.

```
Q(x) * T_2L(x)
= Q(x) * (T_L(x) - x^L * E_L(x) * T_L(x))
= Q(x) * T_L(x) * (1 - x^L * E_L(x))
= (1 + x^L * E_L(x)) * (1 - x^L * E_L(x))
= 1^2 - (x^L * E_L(x))^2
= 1 + x^2L * E_2L(x)
```

Q.E.D.

I am pretty sure it is not possible to compute polynomial division more efficient than multiplication, and as you can see in the following table, this algorithm is only 3 times slower than a single multiplication:

```
   n      mul        inv      factor
10^4       24 ms      80 ms    3,33x
10^5      318 ms     950 ms    2,99x
10^6    4.162 ms  12.258 ms    2,95x
10^7  101.119 ms 294.894 ms    2,92x
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the system you'd get with your plan, you can see that it is already diagonal, and doesn't require O(n^3) to be solved. It simply degenerates into a linear recursion (P[], Q[] and R[] being the coefficients of the corresponding polynomials):

```
R[0] = P[0]/Q[0]
R[n] = (P[n] - sum{0..n-1}(R[i] * Q[n-i]))/Q[0]
```

Since Q is a polynomial, the sum has no more than `deg(Q)` terms (thus taking constant time to calculate), making the overall complexity asymptotically linear. You may also look at the matrix representation of recursion for a (possibly) better asymptotic.

Comment: It is linear for  one R(i) value, however for all values R(0), ..., R(n) it becomes *O(n^2)*

Comment: No. It would become O(n^2) if Q had infinite number of coefficients. The sum has no more terms than deg(Q), so it takes constant time to calculate. I will edit my answer - it is unclear. Thanks.

Comment: Then it becomes O(n*q), where q - degree of Q. Seems the same as in the accepted post.